# itext pdf doesn't show table when setHeaderRows

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tabular

I created a table with N columns header using setHeaderRows(N), when I add to the table N-1 records and deploy, nothing is displayed, i.e. if I create a table that has 5 columns header and just add 4 records or less to the table, nothing is displayed.

Sample Code

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(605, 784), 28, 28, 42, 28);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new   FileOutputStream("/temp/tabla.pdf"));
documento.open();
// Create table
PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(5);
tabla.setComplete(false);
tabla.setWidthPercentage(100);
tabla.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
tabla.setHeaderRows(5);
// Add Header Rows 
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
  celda = new PdfPCell();
  Paragraph encabezado = new Paragraph("Header "+i);        
  celda.addElement(encabezado);
  celda.setGrayFill(0.8f);
  tabla.addCell(celda);
}              
// Add some cells               
for(int k=0; k<19; k++)
{
  celda = new PdfPCell();
  Paragraph contenido = new Paragraph("Cell "+k, helvetica11);
  celda.addElement(contenido);                      
  tabla.addCell(celda);
}
// In total add 4 rows

tabla.completeRow(); 
document.add(tabla);
document.close();
```

Normally the table cells are filled with data from a SQL query, which can return one or many records, I have filled the table with a single "for" cycle to show malfunction.

Someone could help me how to solve this problem? What parameter should I set? or any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table consists of nothing but header rows. There is no real data in your table.

You should change:

```
tabla.setHeaderRows(5);
```

Into:

```
tabla.setHeaderRows(1);
```

Comment: if you see the code in section comment // Add some cells -- add some cells but it is only demo table on really the table is populate with data from sql query

Comment: The code works correctly while the number of rows add is >= 5 but  any sql query, get fewer records

Comment: effectively in this case it was only necessary one row Header